# CameraUtils.java:154: warning: [deprecation] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

1. I upgraded the old project and tried to migrate it to the null-safety I am getting this error can't get any answers regarding that any help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your build.gradle file under the app folder, change your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSDKVersion` to 31 or if on Android 13, then sdkVersion to 33, and see if that resolves your issue. Also check to see that your camera package is up to date. If that doesn't work, you can use use their temporary fix with adding this to your pubspec.yaml folder under dependency_overrides:

```
camera_android:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bottlepay/plugins.git
      path: packages/camera/camera_android
      ref: e1a4dba770da9bc3cf9f858bac6837083f8b9059
```

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89578, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93714

There is also an open issue as of this writing on the problem with the app crashing- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109769

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Those are just warnings and you can safely ignore them for now. I've been getting the same warnings, and the application still functions as expected.

If you're getting issues, please post them here with a sample of your code and we can see if there are possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually 7 of them is `warning` but 1 of them is `error` which will block you to successfully have a build.